# ASP.Net dropdownlist not returning index on selectedindexchanged event

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist control with a selectedindexchanged *event that fires correctly*.  However, when you select an item from the list the index value that is returned to the selectedindexchanged event does not change; the list box pops back tot he first item in the list.  Any help would be appreciated.   ~susan~

**ASP DROP DOWN LIST CONTROL**:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="CuisineList" runat="server" Width="100" 
    AutoPostBack = "true" onselectedindexchanged="CuisineList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

**DATA BOUND TO CONTROL IN PAGELOAD EVENT:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //Load drop down lists for restaurant selection

    BLgetMasterData obj = new BLgetMasterData();

    var cusineList = obj.getCuisines();
    CuisineList.DataSource = cusineList;
    CuisineList.DataBind();
    CuisineList.Items.Insert(0, "Any");
```

**SELECTEDINDEXCHANGEDEVENT:**

```
   protected void CuisineList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string def = this.CuisineList.SelectedItem.Value;
            //aLWAYS returns index '0'
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you triggering the event?  Are you using the keyboard or mouse?  Believe it or not, I've run into problems where one method works and the other does not!

Comment: What is the value bound to? If the value is always zero, then selected item will be the first one in the list with value = 0 - i.e. 'Any'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to put your Dropdownlist binding code under `!IsPostBack()` in the page_load event. like...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
  BLgetMasterData obj = new BLgetMasterData();

  var cusineList = obj.getCuisines();
  CuisineList.DataSource = cusineList;
  CuisineList.DataBind();
  CuisineList.Items.Insert(0, "Any");
 }
}
```

**Reason:** Whenever your `SelectedIndex` Change Event fires, the `Page_load` event is called before the `SelectedIndex` Change event and your dropdown data `rebinded`, that's why your `currect selection was lost`.